# Storing value in unknown depth of multidimensional array

Tags: php, indexing, depth

I have this exath path saved somewhere:

```
Array
(
    [0] => library
    [1] => 1
    [2] => book
    [3] => 0
    [4] => title
    [5] => 1
)
```

I have some array and I want to change the value on this index:

```
$values[library][1][book][0][title][1] = "new value";
```

I have no idea, how to do this, because there can be any (unknown) number of dimensions. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense to create a function that does this, so:

```
function array_path_set(array & $array, array $path, $newValue) {
    $aux =& $array;
    foreach ($path as $key) {
        if (isset($aux[$key])) {
            $aux =& $aux[$key];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    $aux = $newValue;
    return true;
}
$values = array(
    'library' => array(
        1 => array(
            'book' => array(
                0 => array(
                    'title' => array(
                        1 => 'MAGIC VALUE!',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
$path = array('library', 1, 'book', 0, 'title', 1);
$newValue = 'ANOTHER MAGIC VALUE!';

var_dump($values);
var_dump(array_path_set($values, $path, $newValue));
var_dump($values);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well. Tested and it does not ovewrite other values in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
foreach ($array as $val) {
   $indexes .= "[$val]";
}
${'output'.$indexes} = 'something';
```

Or

```
$indexes = '';
foreach ($array as $val) {
   $indexes .= "[$val]";
}
$output = 'values'.$indexes;
$$output = 'something';
```

Comment: Test: set this N-dimensional array.
`$output["library"][1]["book"][0]["title"][1] = "old value";`
and tried to access to it:
`${'output["library"][1]["book"][0]["title"][1]'} = "new value";` .. But if I `print_r($output)`, the value remains unchanged

Comment: How about the changes I did on my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to provide a new value for the title  of book 0 in library 1?  If so, you will have to search for library "1", with book "0" and then change the value of the "title".  So if all your values in the array have the same six entries, start with loc = 0 look at the values at loc+1 (library id), loc+3 (book id) and loc+5 .. change title) .. if not increment loc by 6 and continue searching.

[sounds like homework, so no code provided. Pardon me if I am wrong.]

Comment: Thanks .. I don't need the code, I just need to know some hints. Well, yes, I can easily read the data, but how can I change them?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you weren't aware of it, the key

$values["library"][1]["book"][0]["title"][1]

Is not the same as the array example in your post. Presuming the array is $values, it has five elements:

```
$values = Array
(
    [0] => "library"
    [1] => 1
    [2] => "book"
    [3] => 0
    [4] => "title"
    [5] => 1
)
$values[0] = "Library";
$values[1] = "1";
$values[2] = "book";
$values[3] = "0";
etc...
```

Is this array structure what you intended? If not, post back with a more complete structure so we can help.

Also, you need quotes around the strings - I have included for clarity

You could take a look at the following [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) for array_search. Some of the posters have included examples of a multidimensional array search and there are other examples. Do a google search on "multidimensional array search" and you will likely find a solution. If you need more direction, post back your details.

Comment: I guess he has two different arrays, one which contains the indexes for the other array; and the second one which is multi-dimension with unknown depth

Answer (score 0):

try this ->

```
$keys = array('0'=>'for','1'=>'test','2'=>'only');
$value='ok';

function addArrayPathWithValue($keys,$value,$array = array(),$current = 
array())
{
    $function = __FUNCTION__;

    if (count($current)==0)
    {
        $keys = array_reverse($keys);
        $current = $value;
    }

    if (count($keys)==0)
    {
       return $current;
    }

    $array[array_shift($keys)]=$current;

    return $function($keys,$value,NULL,$array);
}

$array = addArrayPathWithValue($keys,$value);
print_r($array);
//output: Array ( [for] => Array ( [test] => Array ( [only] => ok ) ) )
```